# Opening a URL but with a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble opening a URL with a list as the URL extension. What I mean by this is I open a .txt file (which works fine) and I have put each line of that text file into a list. Now all I want to do is open the given URL with the list at the end, you will see what I mean in the code.

This is where I put the file into a list:

```
with open( filename , 'r' ) as f:
    usernames = [line.strip() for line in f]
print( usernames )
```

And this is what I am trying to accomplish with the URL:

```
url = 'http://twitter.com/'+usernames[0]
if sys.platform == 'darwin':    #in case of OS X
    subprocess.Popen(['open', url ])
else:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab( url )
```

It's only opening http://twitter.com/ and not http://twitter.com/ (word from list here)

Thank you

Comment: Most probably you have a blank line in `filename`...

Comment: This is also probably a typo:

It's only opening http://twitter.com/ and not http://twitter.com/ 

^ Those are the same thing

Comment: Thanks for the replies. There are no blank lines, I tried multiple strings from the list, Bernie. Not sure what you mean Colin. I put in brackets (word from list here)